# unable to see local callback variables when debugging

Tags: node.js, debugging

I am using Webstorm 2016.1.3 and latest nodejs 6.x. I have below simple code.

```
var express     =   require("express");
var app         =   express();
var router      =   express.Router();

router.get("/:url",function(req,res){
    url1 = req.params.url;
    url2 = new Buffer(url1, 'base64').toString();
    console.log(url2);
    res.json({"test" : false,"url" : `${url2}`});
});

app.use('/',router);

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Listening to PORT 3000");
```

When i set the breakpoint at `res.json` i expected to see the `url1` and `url2` variables in the debugger but they don't appear. The `console.log` does show correct contents of `url2` though.

I'm new to nodejs and learning. Am i doing something dumb or is this expected behaviour with debugging javascript ? If so, how can you debug this info ?

Thanks

Comment: hmm won't that give you runtime error? since `url1` and `url2` is not initialized. .e.g `let url1 = req.params.url` instead.

Comment: thanks... prefixing variable with `let` or `var` does make the variables appear in the debug which is great. But without `let` it still works OK, no runtime error and output is as expected.